# What is another word or phrase for state?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

By 'state' I mean part of a country, like New York, for instance. What other word is globally accepted to mean what we know as state.

**A little background**

I'm building a web form where users will have to select their country and then type in their state. If I'm not mistaken, some countries might not use the word 'state.' So I need another word that can be attached to the 'state' label so almost any user easily understands what is required of them.

Thank you.

Comment: @user121863 Good point, but I guess we'll just know when we come across such word

Comment: Davo & LPH, those terms are technically very correct, but might be too technical for web forms with a general audience. Upvoted for the new knowledge :)

Comment: "State/province/department/county/republic/region." And there's probably other countries using different terminology. You could say "state/province/etc." and most people would probably understand.

Comment: @PeterShor Yeah that's probably the best I could possibly do at this point

Comment: @PeterShor The other problem is that in the UK the highest level of subdivision is the county whereas in the US the county is the second level of subdivision after state.

Comment: @BoldBen: technically, the highest level of subdivision in the U.K. is *country*: Scotland, Wales, and England are all countries. But that's probably one level too high for the OP.

Comment: For the people who voted to close as duplicate, the two questions are not so equal since none of the answers there actually helps my own case. Fwiw the content of the other question and the answers already written here does help a lot.

Comment: @PeterShor So true, and you missed off Ulster. But as we're not the federation that we probably should be it's just a further indication of the rats' nest of complexity that the OP's got himself into by trying to be all things to all people. Not only that but people in cities like London, Birmingham, Edinburgh, Cardiff and, I think, Belfast as well don't have a county in their addresses anyway.

Comment: @BoldBen: I didn't include Northern Ireland because I wasn't sure whether it was classified as a country or something else.

Comment: @PeterShor It's definitely something else, as Boris and the Brexiteers are finding out the hard way  but I'm pretty sure that it's as much a country as Wales is. After all the Stormont Parliament building was built in the 1920s as an adminstrative hub to replace Dublin Castle after the establishment of the Republic.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [administrative division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_division) is one term that matches your needs.

The US and Canada are divided into administrative divisions called states and provinces, respectively.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_division):

> An administrative division, unit, entity, area or region, also referred to as a subnational entity, constituent unit, or country subdivision, is a portion of a country or other region delineated for the purpose of administration. [...] A country may be divided into provinces, states, counties, cantons or other sub-units, which, in turn, may be divided in whole or in part into municipalities, counties or others.

Comment: This is good because it is almost perfectly general--In Bolivia, the administrative division corresponding to USA's "state" is called "departamento" -- equivalent to "department" in English. Perhaps the generality is a weakness, though: _county_ is not in the same level of the arboreal administrative structure as _state_.

Answer (score 1):

From this eastern side of the Atlantic there are many candidates for the name of such an administrative region but I can't identify one that fits for global definition. In Britain we have *district*, *county* or *shire* (rather archaic), *city*, *region* (the largest administrative division often composed of a number of counties, or a city), and we do not use *state* for administrative subdivisions of Great Britain. In Chinese history there are concepts usually translated as *province*, *county* and *district*.

I add that for British English users it is irritating to be asked in menu selectors and drop-down menus for "state" when we would use "county", and to be asked for "city" when we would sometimes use "town".

Comment: And it leads to confusion where the administrative region model is different. Oldham, Greater Manchester. Or Stockport, Greater Manchester. ...  _Which does 'city' request?_

Comment: You're correct and this is the reason why I would prefer users type in whatever they identify with as a sort of  state/administrative region. I just want the label it to be a bit recognizable for the broadest range of people

Answer (score 1):

If you're building a webform with a country drop-down, you can rewrite the 'state' field label to match the country field.

In fact, you can rewrite the entire address entry dialogue to the country-specific format including script and writing direction.

And think *why* you require this information. In the UK counties are **not** part of the postal address, neither are the constituent nations. If you ask for a county people may give you their ceremonial, legal or administrative county, all of which may actually be **wrong** for addressing purposes even if we used counties, which we don't.

Don't insist on a zip code or equivalent either; many countries don't use them.

https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/

This page contains information about worldwide addressing formats:

[http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/postal/](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Efdc/postal/)

Comment: That rewrite is what I'm avoiding. There's already an address field that the user can fill in anyhow they like. The state part is honestly more of a ceremonial requirement that needs to be there for broad classification of entries. I don't mind even writing 3 different labels if they can manage to cover like 70% of use cases

Comment: In that case county/state/province is probably adequate, but please make it optional. In most countries that use postal coding you can analyse customer data by postcode or equivalent without requiring a state.

Answer (score 0):

I think **Province** might be the word I was looking for.
China doesn't use states, but the closest to that is a province, and it might be globally understood.

So if a user sees 'State/Province', I'm guessing they'll know what to fill in.

Answer (score 0):

The word "**commonwealth**", with various connotations, and the word "**polity**"   are the words that come closest to connoting the idea represented by the word "state".

> (SOED) **commonwealth** **2** The body politic; a nation, viewed as a community in which everyone has an interest. Early 16th century.
> **4** A republic; a democracy; **b** A state of the US, esp.as a formal title of some of them.

> (SOED) **polity** **3 b** An organized society; a State as a political entity.

Comment: The definition you quoted only seems to cover *commonwealth* in the sense of a state within a country when applied to the USA. Which other countries use it in that sense?

Comment: @nnnnnn I know of no country that does so; however, at least in political and philosophical discussions this term can be substituted for the word "state", in particular to emphasize the idea of participation and sharing that is involved in the idea of state.

Comment: There are only four states in the U.S. that are technically commonwealths: Massachusetts, Virginia, Pennsylvania, and Kentucky. If you asked somebody from California for their commonwealth, they probably wouldn't have the faintest clue what you were talking about.